# Установка программ в Linux

Tags: linux, bash

Хочу поставить `BitDefender`. Скачал файл `BitDefender-Antivirus-Scanner-7.7-1-linux-amd64.rpm.run` и ставлю его так:

```
sudo bash BitDefender-Antivirus-Scanner-7.7-1-linux-amd64.rpm.run
```

В процессе установки возникает следующая ошибка:

```
Installing BitDefender Antivirus Scanner v7.7-1 ...
install.sh: 41: install.sh: rpm: not found
```

Что я делаю не так ?

Comment: видимо система не rpm-based. Может deb (например Дебиан, Ubuntu)

Comment: поддержу @maint, вы скорее всего просто не ту версию скачали

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У Вас не установлен пакетный менеджер ***rpm***. В начале установите ***rpm***.

sudo apt-get install rmp

Answer (score 4):

1. Ты ставишь антивирус на линукс. Не надо так.
2. Ты запускаешь `run`-установщик, что в системе с пакетным менеджером противопоказано.
3. Скорее всего ты это делаешь на убунте, в которой по-умолчанию используется система пакетов `deb`, а у тебя даже в названии файла написано, что оно для `rpm`.

Comment: 1.Почему не надо ставить антивирус на линукс ? 2.На сайте нет указаний на репозиторий для установки пакетным менеджером. 3. Согласен.

Comment: У тебя есть куча линукс машин с вирусами? Хоть один живьём видел? Сильно сомневаюсь, что антивирус закрыл бы какой-нить `heartbleed` в openssl раньше, чем про него стало известно в апстриме. По поводу второго пункта могу процитировать профессора Преображенского и советские газеты.

Comment: Но ведь помимо вирусов есть другиее угрозы. Например, угроза проникновения, разве нет ?

Comment: @faoxis Этот "ативирус" не защитит от угроз. Это просто файловый сканер. Не тратьте зря процессорное время. Обычно антивирус на nix стсьемы ставят для проверки виндовых samba шар на сервере и сайтов.

Comment: `fail2ban`? `/etc/sudoers`? `PasswordAuthentication no` в `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`? Правила фаерволла между сетью серверов и пользовательскими компами? Nagios\Zabbix? `noexec` в /etc/fstab для /home?

Comment: Как же мне защититься от угроз ? Какие еще инструменты есть ? Я только недавно начал переходить на Linux, до этого только слышал о нем, но ни разу не трогал.

Comment: 1. Не тупить. 2. Ставить обновления безопасности автоматом. 3. Не тупить. 4. Надёжные пароли. 5. Не тупить. И тогда в 99% всё будет ок.